Improving insulation of finished attic
I just moved into a 1930s house with a finished attic with knee walls which is not original to the house, though I don’t know when it was finished. I’m having an issue where the AC seems to be working properly, but the house does not stay cool. After poking around in the attic I’ve found that there is what appears to be blown in cellulose between the rafters (even behind the knee wall), but nothing in the floor between any of the joists that would block air coming in from the soffits from entering the house. Is this normal or would insulating the floor between the knee walls and the roof decking help my situation? Would insulating the knee walls themselves provide any additional benefit?

I'm curious how you can have cellulose "behind the knee wall" without it also being in the joist bay (which would prevent air from getting under the floor).

If the finished attic is intended to be part of the living space, then there normally isn't insulation between it and the rest of the living space, just as there isn't insulation between the ground floor and second floor. You can put a layer of insulation there, but that will make the attic space warmer in the summer than the rest of the house, and colder in winter, unless you are actively conditioning that space with its own ducts or heat exchanger.
Converted attics are a trade-off. They are a relatively cheap way to get additional space. But they are harder to condition, and they do rob the house of some opportunity for insulation. In my own house, I chose not to use the attic as either living space or storage space, allowing me to blow in a 3 foot deep layer of insulation. You can't get both unless you raise the roof. In which case, you might as well add a real additional floor, and then have a fully insulated attic again.
If you haven't already done so, have the house air sealed. That's another relatively low cost, high impact step you can take towards energy efficiency.
Your utility company may have programs that will help pay for a basic efficiency survey and some remediation.
